# Calling function in xcode iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

If I have this function for button click

```
-(IBAction)loginButton:(UIButton *)sender{ }
```

How can I call this button function from this another method

```
-(void)increaseAmount {
myNumber = myNumber+0.01;

if (myNumber >= 1) {

    [self loginButton:sender];   

}

progressViewAuto.progress = myNumber;}
```

I have tried the above code but getting error that USE OF UNDECLARED IDENTIFIER 'sender'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And, if you want to be perfectly correct, you can link your UIButton to `IBOutlet UIButton* theLoginButton;` and then say `[self loginButton:theLoginButton];`.

But this would only be needed if you actually reference the sender in your loginButton routine, and that's the exception rather than the rule.

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass in `nil` or even `self`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want to send `nil`, like this:

```
[self loginButton:nil];
```